# Can I create special functions like %in% just one input (LEFT) or (RIGHT)?

Tags: r, function, alias

The common notation for `factorial` is the `!` operator in mathematics.

I can create function:

```
"%!%" = function(n, r=NULL) { factorial(n); }
```

This works as expected if I pass a `NULL` or `NA` to the RHS, which I don't really want to do.

```
3 %!% NA

3 %!% NULL

3 %!% .
```

What I would like to do is just enter:

```
3 %!%
```

Any suggestions on HOW I can do that?  In that setup, I want the LHS (left) to be the input and the RHS (right) to be ignored.

I can do the BOTH no problem:

```
nPr = function(n, r, replace=FALSE) 
    { 
    if(replace) { return( n^r ); }
    factorial(n) / factorial(n-r); 
    }
"%npr%" = "%nPr%" = nPr;

nCr = function(n, r, replace=FALSE) 
    { 
    # same function (FALSE, with n+r-1)
    if(replace) { return( nCr( (n+r-1), r, replace=FALSE ) ); } 
    factorial(n) / ( factorial(r) * factorial(n-r) ); 
    }
"%ncr%" = "%nCr%" = nCr;
```

where

```
5 %nCr% 3
5 %nPr% 3
```

work as expected based on selection without replacement.

How to use the special operator with just the LHS?

The follow-on question is the opposite.  Let's say I want the LHS (left) to be ignored and focus on the RHS (right).  I believe this is how the built-in `?` function links to `help` and `??` links to `help.search()`.  Let's say I wanted to create an %$$% operator that worked that way.

Comment: I don't know, just want to do a remark regarding your last question: this would be similar to the negation operator `!` or to the bang-bang operator `!!` in the **rlang** package. Maybe take a look at how `!!` is implemented.

Comment: I am baffled that the single dot `.` works ?!?  I will look into `!!` and certainly I use `!` as the NOT operator all of the time.  `n!` is very common in mathematics, and currently I am getting `n %!%.` to work with the mysterious dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that.  The `%any%` operators are defined by the parser to be binary operators.

You can see all of the operators in R in the `?Syntax` help page.  Some are binary, some are unary, and some can be either one, but the unary operators always precede the argument.  You can attach different functions to most of them (e.g. change the meaning of `!` in `!x`), but you can't change the parser to allow `x!` to be legal code.

Comment: I am baffled that the single dot `.` works ?!?

Comment: The dot is an identifier, not an operator.